# Understanding definition of product topology

Tags: general-topology

> Definition given in book: Let $X_\alpha$ be topological spaces, and consider the weak topology ON $X=\prod_{\alpha\in\Omega} X_\alpha$ generated by $\{\pi_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in \Omega}$, then a product of non empty open sets $\prod_{\alpha \in \Omega} U_\alpha$ is open in $X$ if and only if $X_\alpha=U_\alpha$ for all but finitely many $\alpha$.

Now I was trying to understand this by looking at an example: Consider $X_\alpha =\{a,b,c\}$ Then consider topology on each is $\{\emptyset, X_\alpha,\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. Then let $\prod U_\alpha=\{(a,a,a,a,\dots)\} $ for which $U_\alpha=\{a\}$ for all $\alpha$, then clearly the product of those open sets is open in $X$ but $U_\alpha \neq X_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.

I've not be understanding some ideas correctly, can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, how is it open in $X$? For something to be open in $X$, you first need a topology on $X$?

Comment: Product of open sets need not be open.

Comment: You don't get to pick the topology on the product space. It is induced by the projection maps. It is the coarsest topology that makes the projection maps continuous.

Comment: "then clearly the product of those open sets is open" - no, check the definition.

Comment: The definition of open sets under the product topology is $\bigcap^n_{i=1}\pi^{-1}_\alpha(U_\alpha)$. If we have Card($\Omega)=2$ If we have $\pi^{-1}_1(U_1)\cap \pi_2^{-1}(U_2)=\{(a, a)\}$ which is open, then I would assume when we consider infinite case, the preimage would be open as well?